# How to add variable in language file opencart2

Tags: opencart

I am trying to add a variable in language file using opencart extension, but there is no change in the file.

My code:

```
<file path="admin/language/english/catalog/product.php">
  <operation>
    <search><![CDATA[// Error]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[
             $_['entry_a_start_date']    = 'Start Date/Time';
           ]]>
        </add>
  </operation>
</file>`
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you want to call a single file use `name` not `path`.

This should work:

```
<file name="admin/language/english/catalog/product.php">
  <operation>
    <search position="before"><![CDATA[// Error]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
             $_['entry_a_start_date']    = 'Start Date/Time';
           ]]>
        </add>
  </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: I have to do modification in multiple files like view and language , Also I have used name instead of path but still it does not work

Comment: I edited my code and moved  `position="before"` from `add` to `search` tag, now check it again.

Comment: You can do `<search position="after"><![CDATA[<?php]]></search>` to ensure it gets inserted and save time since it works on all language files.